# Can't insert null values on @ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

I'm getting this error when I try to persist an `A class Object`:

```
Detail: Key (classB)=() is not present in table "b".
```

I need to have the possibility to insert the object with null on the referenced column.

The problem is hibernate convert the null value on an empty string, so when I try to persist the object, it fails.

If I put `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on `@ManyToOne` works, but it creates a row on `B table` with ID = 0 and an empty string as `refColName` value. I want to avoid this because de A class is the child, and the cascade should be in B class.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class A {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "class_b", referencedColumnName = "refColName", nullable = true)
    private B classB;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table
public class B {
    ...

    @Id
    @Column (name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "refColName")
    private String refColName;
    ...
}
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks for your time

Edit:

It's a unidirectional relationship, where B is a master data table, so i have predefined values. refColName should be a String. I use referencedColumnName because I can´t take the id as a foreign key.

Comment: referenced`Column is not a string. It must be a Set/List of object A

Comment: It's a unidirectional relationship, where B is a master data table, so i have predefined values. refColName should be a String. I use referencedColumnName because I can´t take the id as a foreign key.

Comment: try making @ManyToOne optional

Comment: Doesn't work. I still getting the same error. I've tried a few answers I see but doesn't work anything.

Comment: 'the A class is the child, and the cascade should be in B class' - why not use a unidirectional `@OneToMany` association with a join column, then? Also, are you by any chance using Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to have the possibility to insert the object with null on the
>   referenced column.

Please make sure the classA input to persist should be like below(representing in json)

```
{
  classB:null
}
```

and not

```
{
  classB:{
    refColName:null
  }
}
```